# my function returns me a function but it showing me error , No Output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to return a function but it doesn't work:

```
def to_power(x): # x = 3
    def calc_power(num): # num = 2
        return num**x # 2**3 = 8
    return calc_power()


cube = to_power(3)
print(cube(5))
```

My code is giving me this error:

> TypeError: calc_power() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num'

However, I'm pretty sure I did give an argument:

```
cube = to_power(3)
    print(cube(5)) # arg = 5
```

Comment: Why are you returning a function? why not just do the calculation within the to_power function?

Comment: because i'm learning python and i wanna learn how function works when some other function returns the function ....btw i got it now ..

Comment: I'd recommend learning the basics of function calls (i.e., a function with a signature of `def func(x):...` has one required positional argument) before diving further in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the function, only the return value (which will never even compute because of the missing argument). Get rid of the parentheses:

```
def to_power(x): # x = 3
    def calc_power(num):
        return num**x
    return calc_power
```

Now, if you do the rest:

```
cube = to_power(3)
print(cube(5))
```

You will get

```
125
```

Comment: Ohh i got it sir , Thank you . that was silly mistake .

Comment: @AnkitSingh No problem. If this solved your question, please consider accepting this answer for future viewers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: yeah definitely Sir why not , and please vote my question because i am new in python thats why making sillly mistakes but it's a worthy question for a beginner so please vote my question sir ..